# .NET Oracle SP call errors ORA-00604 and ORA-01001 when passing CTE-based cursor to application

Tags: .net, oracle, cursor, common-table-expression

The SP is as follows: [SP code](http://pastebin.com/nknGhSM2)

C# code calling it: [C# code](http://pastebin.com/TLV1rxCf) (this is the version after making changes described in update #3)

Using System.Data.OracleClient, .NET 3.5 SP1, Oracle Express 11g, Windows 7 x64.

This executes fine in SQL Developer(2,3). However, when calling from .NET, this happens: (see update 3)

**Update 1:** Using ExecuteReader with 2 OUT parameters *works*, when the cursor parameter is reading a global temp. table joined with a regular table. Also, this will eventually have to work inside an ORM (Lightspeed) which can only use ExecuteReader.

**Update 2:** Looks like same thing happens inside SQL Developer. I used this:

```
LOOP
  FETCH results INTO v_rec;
  EXIT WHEN results%notfound;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec.name);
END LOOP;
```

... to fetch the contents of "results": works in the SP, and produces ORA-01001 when used in the PL/SQL block calling the SP (after removing the same code inside the SP, of course).

**Update 3:** Turning "results1" into an OUT parameter solved the problem in SQL Developer, which apparently was cursor being automatically closed when going out of scope. However, .NET now barfs:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01059: parse expected before a bind or execute
```

See [C# code](http://pastebin.com/TLV1rxCf) for parameters. Tried ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteOracleNonQuery methods, to no avail.

Comment: don't think that will solve your problem, but why don't you close the cursor ?

Comment: A.B.Cade - not sure what you mean. I need the cursor open so .NET can read from it. Adding *results1* as an OUT param keeps *results* open, which allowed the PL/SQL in SQL Developer to read *results*. Problem now is .NET apparently generates erroneous SQL.

Comment: My mistake, I mixed results1 and results

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the `System.Data.OracleClient` classes since I usually use Oracle's ODP.NET. So I can only give you some hints:

Typically, when you have an Oracle stored procedure., you call `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader` since Oracle never directly returns a result set from a stored procedure. Using `ExecuteReader` might work if you have a single `OUT` paramter of type `CURSOR`. But you have two of them.

What should work in any case, is to call `ExecuteNonQuery` and then retrieve the `OUT` parameters:

```
int totalNumRows = (int)command.Parameters["total_num_rows"].Value;

using (var reader = (OracleDataReader)cmd.Parameters["results"].Value)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        temp.Add(new Blah { Name = (string)reader["name"] });
    }
}
```

P.S. The `System.Data.OracleClient` classes are deprected.